# Read variables in nested quotes

Tags: bash, ssh

I want to ssh into a host and start a container and run some commands. So the code will be like this:

```
ssh $host 'screen -L -d -m bash -c "docker run "\
  "--network=host -v ~/data:/data myimage:${TAG_NAME}"\
  " /bin/bash -c \" some command.... \""'
```

The question is simple, since I was using single quote, I can't read the `${TAG_NAME}`. Is there any way to write this kind of nested quotes and also pass the variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can stop and start your single quotes to include the environment variable, like so:

```
echo 'foo'"$HOME"'foo'
```

For your example, the way to include an env var (from your local system) in the command that runs on `$host` would be:

```
ssh $host 'screen -L -d -m bash -c "docker run'\
 ' --network=host -v ~/data:/data myimage:'"$TAG_NAME"\
 ' /bin/bash -c \" some command.... \""'
```

Comment: Variable references should (almost) always be double-quoted. In this situation, that means ending the single-quoted section, starting a double-quoted section, using the variable, then ending the double-quoted section and starting a new single-quoted section: `echo 'foo'"$HOME"'foo'`